# Arguments of boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost

Does anyone know why boost bind takes address of member function but for non-member functions does not require address.

For example:

```
boost::bind( &CMyClass::doSomething, this );
```

vs

```
boost::bind( RegularFunction );
```

In theory could boost have had implementation be so one could bind as follows:

```
boost::bind( CMyClass::doSomething, this );
```

or would this not work ?

Comment: It's not just boost::bind - taking the address of a member function always requires the use of the `&` operator, taking the address of a normal function does not. That's the way the language is specified.

Comment: Thanks.  I did not realize that C++ required passing member functions that way.